# How SailsJS connects to mysql with replication failover?

Tags: mysql, sails.js, database-replication, automatic-failover

I have developed an application using SailsJS, using sails-mysql adapter. I want to setup replication and automatic failover for MySQL. In a typical java application using JConnector, I would have specify the master and slave configuration on my connection string. What about SailsJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of digging around the net. I have found the solution to use HAProxy to load balance MySQL nodes. My sails-mysql adapter will only connect to HAProxy address. There is an awesome tutorial here to setup HAProxy with MySQL.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-to-set-up-http-load-balancing-on-an-ubuntu-vps